# Wanted to Update Title and Image in Angular after component load

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, renderer

Wanted to update Dom elements like Image and Text after loading component in Angular. Note: Both of them does not have ID but have Class Name.

I used following code:

```html
@ViewChild('.appnametitle') el: ElementRef;
  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document,
    @Inject(ONEPLACE_JS_URI) private oneplaceJsUri,
    public cookieConfig: CookieConfig
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'innerHTML', 'Test Title Change');
  }
```

but it shows following error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement')

Could you help me where I am doing it wrong?

Comment: are you sure you have to use `renderer`? Please show some HTML code.
can't you just use data binding? like `{{title}}`

Answer (score 0):

ViewChild has not a classname as selector (a [directive yes](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector)). So you can create a directive with the selector of the class and use ViewChild asking about the directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.appnametitle'
})
export class SelectDirective {

  constructor(public el:ElementRef) { }

}
```

And in Component:

```
@ViewChild(SelectDirective) selectDirective:SelectDirective

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.selectDirective.el.nativeElement,
              'innerHTML', 'Test Title Change');
  }
```

But this is used if you has not access to the component (because was on third persons, e.g.), else you should rethinking the problem in a more angular way